# `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file` when trying to connect Python pipeline

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, piping

I've attempted to simplify piping Python Popen processes into each other using the following code. The idea is that Process represents a process with arguments (but without a stdout or stdin), and then the `pipe` function connects them up.

```
def Process(parameters, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Represents a process that can be piped into another
    """
    parameters = [str(p) for p in parameters]

    # Partially apply the constructor, so we can handle the piping later
    return functools.partial(subprocess.Popen, parameters, *args, **kwargs)


def pipe(commands, stdin=None):
    """
    Pipes a series of commands into each other
    :param commands: An array of commands, each of which is an instance of Process
    :param stdin: stdin to the first command
    :param kwargs: Any extra arguments to pass to subprocess.Popen
    :return:
    """
    # Keep track of previous processes
    processes = []

    # Each process's stdin is the stdout of the previous stage
    for i, cmd in enumerate(commands):
        if i == 0:
            process = cmd(stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        else:
            previous = processes[-1]
            process = cmd(stdin=previous.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

            # Close stdout of previous command so we get SIGPIPE
            previous.stdout.close()

        processes.append(process)

    first = processes[0]
    final = processes[-1]

    if first == final:
        # If we only have one process, return its output
        return first.communicate(stdin)
    else:
        # Pipe input into first process
        first.communicate(stdin)

        # Return Final process
        return final.communicate()
```

However, if I run the pipe function as follows:

```
stdout, stderr = pipe([
    Process(['tr', 'n', '\\n']),
    Process(['rev']),
    Process(['wc', '-l']),
], text)
```

I get the error:

```
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

Notably, this error goes away if I omit the `previous.stdout.close()`. But the [`subprocess` docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline) strongly recommend against that, if I want SIGPIPEs to work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should not immediately close stdout, but close them in the end.

```
if first == final:
    # If we only have one process, return its output
    result = first.communicate(stdin)
    first.stdout.close()
    return first.communicate(stdin)
else:
    # Pipe input into first process
    first.communicate(stdin)

    # Return Final process
    result = final.communicate()
    for process in processes:
        process.stdout.close()
    return result
```

Because `Popen` return at once, your commands are not finished, so stdout is still active.

Comment: Why then do they immediately close it in the [subprocess docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline)?

Comment: @Miguel I think the difference is that `dmesg` will finish writing to stdout but not `tr`. And I am not sure about specific progress, maybe you can use debugger to figure it out.